# How do you figure out the index and also the value of the index in a list at the same time?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a 5x5 playing area. Empty spaces are represented as 0 and the player as 8. I am trying to move the player based on input. I am having trouble knowing the value of an item inside a list while also knowing the index of that item. I tried `enumerate()` but I don't understand how it works:

```
screenLine = "----------------------------------------------------------------";
playingArea = ["", "8", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", ]

def printPlayingArea():
    for i in range(len(playingArea)):
        if i == 5 or i == 10 or i == 15 or i == 20 or i == 25 or i == 30 or i == 35 or i == 40 or i == 45 or i == 50:
            print(playingArea[i])
        elif i == 0:
            print(playingArea[i], end="")
        else:
            print(playingArea[i], end=" ")
    print(screenLine)

async def movePlayer():
    move = input("What direction would you like to go? ")
    print(screenLine)
    for a, b in enumerate(playingArea):
        if a == "8":
            print(a)
            print(b)
movePlayer()
```

Output:

```
What direction would you like to go? right
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

`movePlayer()` doesn't do anything and that is intentional. I am just trying to figure out the problem. The print statements are for testing and it printed nothing. IDE I am using is [Programiz Pro Python Playground](https://programiz.pro/ide/python).

Edit: I acknowledge that I have did a wrong thing by not reading the documentation before posting a question on Stack Overflow. I now know how the enumerate function works. I apologize for any inconvenience I have made.

Comment: `if a == "8":` is never going to be satisfied since `a` is the index. `b` is the value. You should use `if b == "8":` instead. See the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: And you should probably name those something other than `a` and `b` so that this doesn't keep happening.

Comment: @goudyugood what I sometimes do when I'm not sure about how functions work is open up a Python REPL, then run `help(function)` to see if there's built-in documentation I can read. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def enumerate(iterable, start=0):
    n = start
    for elem in iterable:
        yield n, elem
        n += 1
```

The enumerate function work like as it
So you can easily understands what enumerate function does actually

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, it might be worthwhile to read the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77012159/#comment135762892_77012159) and give your variables [better names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77012159/#comment135762911_77012159) to prevent this problem from happening again.

e.g.

```
for square, content in enumerate(playingArea):
    if content == "8":
        print("There is a player on this square.")
    else:
        print("Nope, just an empty square.")
```

Here you would be checking the content of the square, not its index in the list.

Answer (score -3):

> "… *knowing the value of an item inside a list while also knowing the index of that item.*"

Using [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common):

```
value = '8'
try:
    index = playingArea.index(value)
    print(f'playingArea[{index}] = "{playingArea[index]}"')
except ValueError:
    print('Value not present.')
```

Or:

```
value = '8'
if playingArea.count(value):
    index = playingArea.index(value)
    print(f'playingArea[{index}] = "{playingArea[index]}"')
else:
    print('Value not present.')
```

> "*I tried enumerate() but I don't understand how* …"

Using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, value in enumerate(playingArea):
    if value == '8':
        print(f'playingArea[{index}] = "{value}"')
        break
```

Without `enumerate()`:

```
for index in range(len(playingArea)):
    if playingArea[index] == '8':
        print(f'playingArea[{index}] = "{playingArea[index]}"')
        break
```

> "*I am trying to make a 5x5 playing area.*"

Using list of lists:

```
size_x, size_y = 5, 5
area = [[0 for _ in range(size_x)] for _ in range(size_y)]
area[size_x - 1][size_y - 1] = 1

for y in range(size_y):
    for x in range(size_x):
        print(f'area[{y}][{x}] = {area[y][x]}')
```

Existing list as square:

```
x = 5
display = ''

for index in range(len(playingArea)):
    display += str(playingArea[index])
    if not ((index + 1) % x):
        display += '\n'

print(display)
```

> "*I am trying to move the player based on input.*"

Alternatively:

```
def area(position, size_x, size_y):
    area = ''
    for y in range(size_y):
        for x in range(size_x):
            area += 'X' if (x == position[0] and y == position[1]) else '+'
            if x == size_y - 1:
                area += '\n'
    return area


size_x, size_y = 5, 5
position = [0, 0]

while True:
    print(position)
    print(area(position, size_x, size_y))
    match input('wasd: '):
        case 'w':
            position[1] = (position[1] - 1) % size_y
        case 'a':
            position[0] = (position[0] - 1) % size_x
        case 's':
            position[1] = (position[1] + 1) % size_y
        case 'd':
            position[0] = (position[0] + 1) % size_x
        case _:
            exit()
```